# Customize Ext.window.MessageBox ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

Im using Ext.window.MeassageBox for confirmation dialog window.

Code is something like this:

```
deleteSomething: function( grid, row, col ) {
    var ids = [ grid.store.getAt( row ).get( 'id' ) ];

    function deleteSomething ( btn, text ) {
        if( btn === 'yes' ) {
            Ext.Ajax.request( {
                url: 'data/deleteSomething.php',
                params: {
                    'ids': Ext.encode( ids )
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    //perform some actions
                }
            } );
        }
    }

    Ext.MessageBox.show( {
        animEl: 'elId',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
        fn: deleteSomething,
        msg: Locale.gettext( 'Are you sure you want to remove the selected thing?' ),
        title: Locale.gettext( 'Delete?' )
    } );
}
```

I want to apply some css rules for message field and **scale: 'medium'** with right-side align for buttons. Is there any way to achive it without extend MessageBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add `buttons` properties like below?

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
   buttons: [
      {text: 'YES', scale: 'medium'},
      '->',
      {text: 'NO', scale: 'medium}
   ]
});
```

EDIT :
why we don't use a simple `window` component?

```
var winDelete = new Ext.Window({
    width: 300,
    modal: true,
    closeAction: false,
    title: 'Are you sure to delete this record?',
    closable: false,
    html: '<span>The selected records will remove from the list.<br/>Are you sure?</span>',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'YES',
            scale: 'medium',
            cls: 'btn-delete-yes',
            listeners: {
                click: function() {
                    deleteSomething();
                }
            }
        }, '->',
        {
            text: 'NO',
            scale: 'medium',
            cls: 'btn-delete-no',
            listeners: {
               click: function() {
                   winDelete.close();
               }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Just remove '->' part then try again. If its work add cls parameter for css class. Modify that class with float:right

Comment: Ext.MessageBox.show( {
  animEl: 'elId',
  buttons: [
   {
    text: 'YES'
   },
   {
    text: 'NO'
   }
  ],
  fn: deleteRule,
  msg: Locale.gettext( 'Are you sure you want to remove the selected thing?' ),
  title: Locale.gettext( 'Delete?' )
 } );
Even it does not work - buttons still disappeared, maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Dear Sergey, as specified in extjs doc, `buttons` config equivalent to `toolbar` component so why you shouldn't add to toolbar bottom of the window? Or you can make a `window` component.

Comment: Oğuz, thanks for response. Seemns new window components is a proper solution, but I used confirmation window for several different actions so I have to pass function as property or, at least, action type so I can call something like "listeners: { click: function() { doAction( actionType ); } } }.